# Concat two completable RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

My goal is to concat `completable1` and `completable2[0]`. After `doOnComplete()` I am using `mContent` to createThumbnails.I tried the code above ,but it's not working.

```
Completable  completable1;

final Completable[] completable2 = new Completable[1];

completable1 = AppManagers.getContentManager()
    .completeCopy(mContent)
    .toCompletable()
    .doOnComplete(() -> {
        File file = new 
        File(ImageUtils.getThumbNailPathsForLocalContent(mContent.getId(), 0));
        if (!file.exists()) {
            final ContentVideoCache videoCache = 
                AppManagers.getAppContext().getVideoCache();
            Uri dataURI = videoCache.getDataURI(mContent);
            completable2[0] = AppManagers.getContentManager()
                .createThumbnails(mContent.getId(), dataURI)
                .toCompletable();
        }
    });
    completable = completable1.concatWith(completable2[0]);
```

**Update** : if `completeCopy(mContent)` returns me different object of `mContent`

```
 Completable completable = AppManagers.getContentManager()
                                .copyIntoShell((Content) selectedContent, mContent)
                                .flatMapCompletable(new Function<Content, CompletableSource>() {
                                    @io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull
                                    @Override
                                    public CompletableSource apply(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Content content) throws Exception {
                                        return generateThumbnailsForNewContent(content);
                                    }
                                });
```

After this if I `subscribe` to `completable`,it will be completed after   `return generateThumbnailsForNewContent(content);` will be finished right?

```
 private Completable generateThumbnailsForNewContent(Content mContent) {
        File file = new File(ImageUtils.getThumbNailPathsForLocalContent(mContent.getId(), 0));
        if (!file.exists()) {
            final ContentVideoCache videoCache = AppManagers.getAppContext().getVideoCache();
            Uri dataURI = videoCache.getDataURI(mContent);
            return AppManagers.getContentManager().createThumbnails(mContent.getId(), dataURI).toCompletable();
        }
        return Completable.error(new FileNotFoundException());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you try to accomplish here, but `andThen` and `defer` are the operators to have [dependent-deferred continuations](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#deferred-dependent):

```java
AppManagers.getContentManager()
.completeCopy(mContent)
.toCompletable()
.andThen(Completable.defer(() -> {
    File file = new File(ImageUtils.getThumbNailPathsForLocalContent(
        mContent.getId(), 0));

    if (!file.exists()) {
        final ContentVideoCache videoCache = 
            AppManagers.getAppContext().getVideoCache();

        Uri dataURI = videoCache.getDataURI(mContent);

        return AppManagers.getContentManager()
            .createThumbnails(mContent.getId(), dataURI)
            .toCompletable();
    }
    return Completable.error(new FileNotFoundException());
}));
```

Comment: I also have a case where `completeCopy(mContent)` returns me different object of  `mContent`,can I get that object in `Completable.defer(() -> {...}` ?

Comment: What do you mean? You opted out any value via `toCompletable()` so you can't get values that way.

Comment: Ah,okay,I guess I should use `.flatMapCompletable` and  `return AppManagers.getContentManager()
            .createThumbnails(mContent.getId(), dataURI)
            .toCompletable();generateThumbnailsForNewContent(content);`  after `.completeCopy(mContent)` ,in that way the completable will be complited after `.flatMapCompletable` will finish it's return action right?

Comment: I don't understand. Please provide the code for what you are trying now.

Comment: You can try your own ideas and have the answer much quicker.